# Optical Drive to USB (cable type)

Tags: optical-drive

I want to connect my optical drive via usb, but I don't know what kind of cable I need.
The optical drive is a Samsung SN-S082.
Here is a picture of the input:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what kind of cable do I need to buy?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Laptop-IDE-CDROM-DVDROM-to-USB-adapter-9-5mm-Notebook-CD-ROM-DVD-ROM-to-USB-/251169883829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an older IDE Slim Optical drive. I have never found a straight up USB converter for slim non sata ports.

The thing you may want is a board that converts the optical drive to USB, or better, get a kit that has the housing to convert to USB.

[image: ide]

[image: kit]

But, for the cost of a kit, you could get a new external optical drive.